# What are the interesting data structures to work with to manipulate mathematical expressions?

Tags: data-structures, trees, computer-algebra

For learning purposes only, I would like to make a small, fairly basic computer algebra system ([CAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system)) manipulating mathematical expressions, such as polynomials, logarithmic or trigonometric expressions. One of the key features of this style of project is the simplification of expressions. For example, we can ask to simplify $4x²+20x+3xy+15y$ into $(4x+3y)(x+5)$ or $\log(e^{3x - 7})$ into $3x-7$.

A CAS interfaces with the user via a small language and the input is then parsed into an AST. For example, `3*x - 1` might correspond to the following AST: `Sub(Mul(Int 3, Var x), Int 1)`. This AST step is the simplest step for me, my question is about manipulating expressions via this style of tree. The example I showed above on the simplification of $\log(e^{3x - 7})$ is a case of simplification that I would call "simple", it is indeed enough to apply a series of rewriting rules on the AST (with pattern matching for example):

```ocaml
let rec simplify expr =
    match expr with
    | Log (Power (Constant E, x)) -> simplify x
    | ...
    | _ -> expr
```

The other example I gave, however, cannot be solved with pattern matching (at least not as directly, I think), because we don't indeed recognise any pattern, we *manipulate* the expression to transform it.

My question then is how to apply this style of transformation on a tree (the method I used for the example is grouping) and I wonder what kind of data structure could be used to handle this in a way that is perhaps more suitable as I showed by grouping the terms (there is not only one simplification technique, but I remain focused on the question), as manipulating a tree to apply a grouping algorithm seems quite complicated (or I just don't know the algorithms for that structure, in which case I'm interested too). My first idea was simply to turn the tree into a list of terms of the form $Ax^b$ (a monomial), but I don't know if this is useful or not.

So the question is: how to represent an expression to apply simplification algorithms, like the grouping method, on it? Is an AST sufficient? If so, how should it be handled for the style of simplification method I have outlined?

PS: I don't think this question is a duplicate of [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2175/constructing-a-data-structure-for-a-computer-algebra-system) and [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9538/computer-algebra-algorithms-for-solving-equations-symbolically) one, the posts in question are more about building an AST as well as equation solving algorithms, whereas I'm more about what data structure (other than AST, perhaps) to use.

PPS: I'm not especially looking for efficiency (since it's only for learning).

Comment: First off IMHO you are mixing up and confusing the terminology so much that you may never find what you seek. The first example is a factoring, the second example is a simplification. There are many examples of simplification code on GitHub, E.g. [PRESS: PRolog Equation Solving System](https://github.com/maths/PRESS). Do you know why Integral Calculus, Differential Calculus and Lambda Calculus all have the word Calculus in them? Continued.

Comment: For factoring personally I would start with a new set of rules, the reason being that simplification rules try to simplify and factoring requires simplification at times but also requires other means, think about expressions that can not be factored, or how do you know when to stop factoring?

Comment: Of interest: [Canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form)

Comment: Thank you for your comments, it is true that I grouped two operations in one term for simplification and your remark on the term "calculus" was interesting. I'll go for your suggestions.

Comment: Of interest: [Theano](https://theano-pymc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: For factoring, one of the rules I use to determine when to stop for a branch is to check for prime numbers.

Comment: I asked the Calculus question to get an idea of how you think. Since you took it to heart I will give you a hint. The definition I try to use for calculus is that it is a term reduction system that leads to a normal form (in Math they like to use the word canonical form at times). When there are no more rules or reductions that can be applied you have your answer. If given a well formed formula and a proper set of rules the result should be a non-reducible normal form.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations :)

Comment: So obviously all these comments are hinting that it is not the data structure you should focus on but instead understanding term [rewriting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewriting) systems and [confluence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluence_(abstract_rewriting))

Comment: Okay, I see. As I'm a beginner in this field, I was focusing on the technical aspect first (so, how to represent the objects). I'll have a look at it all!

Comment: Before I forget and to be clear on this point. IIRC factoring does not have normal form or canonical form. On the other hand simplification will have a normal for or canonical form.  One can go nuts looking for a normal form or canonical form for factoring if it does not exist and thus one of the early comments. Good luck. Also when you feel confident you should answer you own question here so that others can learn from it.

Comment: Just as an addendum: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/134858